# Getting the same array using Math.random every time. How to generate different array without refreshing the browser?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a sorting visualizer. But when I am creating a array using following code, every time when I create a new array I am getting the same array as previous one! I have to refresh the page to get a new array. What will I have to do in order to get different array without refreshing through browser.

```
let sortingMethod = "";

let array = [];

function between(max) {  
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function createArray() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        array.push(between(20));
    }
    let arena = document.querySelector(".arena");
    arena.innerHTML = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        let element = document.createElement('div');
        element.setAttribute('class', 'element');
        console.log(array[i]);
        element.style.height = (array[i] * 20) + "px"; 
        arena.appendChild(element);
    }
    //console.log("created");
}


let create = document.getElementById("create");

create.addEventListener('click', createArray);
```

Comment: You can combine random number with some information aboute current time (current minute or second).

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: I understand where the problem is now. I will write an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are never clearing your array. So, each time you call `createArray`, new values are just appended to the end of the already filled array, but you only use first 20 values each time.

To solve your problem, just write this part of code `let array = [];` inside your `createArray` function.